# How to deploy nextjs app with githup actions?

Tags: github, next.js, cicd

i am trying to deploy my nextjs app with github actions. I followed github doc:

repo > settings > pages > source = github actions and i added `deploy.yml` which github offers.

```
name: Deploy Next.js site to Pages

on:
  push:
    branches: ["main"]

  workflow_dispatch:

permissions:
  contents: read
  pages: write
  id-token: write

concurrency:
  group: "pages"
  cancel-in-progress: false

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - name: Detect package manager
        id: detect-package-manager
        run: |
          if [ -f "${{ github.workspace }}/yarn.lock" ]; then
            echo "manager=yarn" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
            echo "command=install" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
            echo "runner=yarn" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
            exit 0
          elif [ -f "${{ github.workspace }}/package.json" ]; then
            echo "manager=npm" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
            echo "command=ci" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
            echo "runner=npx --no-install" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
            exit 0
          else
            echo "Unable to determine package manager"
            exit 1
          fi
      - name: Setup Node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v4
        with:
          node-version: "20"
          cache: ${{ steps.detect-package-manager.outputs.manager }}
      - name: Setup Pages
        uses: actions/configure-pages@v4
        with:
          static_site_generator: next
      - name: Restore cache
        uses: actions/cache@v4
        with:
          path: |
            .next/cache
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-nextjs-${{ hashFiles('**/package-lock.json', '**/yarn.lock') }}-${{ hashFiles('**.[jt]s', '**.[jt]sx') }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-nextjs-${{ hashFiles('**/package-lock.json', '**/yarn.lock') }}-
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: ${{ steps.detect-package-manager.outputs.manager }} ${{ steps.detect-package-manager.outputs.command }}
      - name: Build with Next.js
        run: ${{ steps.detect-package-manager.outputs.runner }} next build
      - name: Upload artifact
        uses: actions/upload-pages-artifact@v3
        with:
          path: ./out

  deploy:
    environment:
      name: github-pages
      url: ${{ steps.deployment.outputs.page_url }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    steps:
      - name: Deploy to GitHub Pages
        id: deployment
        uses: actions/deploy-pages@v4
```

When it comes to the Upload Artifact, throws error.

```
Run actions/upload-pages-artifact@v3
  with:
    path: ./out
    name: github-pages
    retention-days: 1
  env:
    GITHUB_PAGES: true
Run tar \
  tar \
    --dereference --hard-dereference \
    --directory "$INPUT_PATH" \
    -cvf "$RUNNER_TEMP/artifact.tar" \
    --exclude=.git \
    --exclude=.github \
    .
  shell: /usr/bin/sh -e {0}
  env:
    GITHUB_PAGES: true
    INPUT_PATH: ./out
tar: dist: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
Error: Process completed with exit code 2.
```

But when i run `npm run build` locally, i can clearly see there is an `out` directory. How can i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Seems like this is the issue.

```
    - name: Setup Pages
      uses: actions/configure-pages@v4
      with:
        static_site_generator: next
```

The above step in the pipeline seems to overwrite the **next.config.js** file. Simply commenting this out or removing it should solve your problem.